# Why this for loop is infinite?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I have such for loop and when step is (0;1) it becomes infinite. If step is [1;..) it works well.

```
  public interface FindMinI {
    double function(double x);

    static double findMinOfFuncOnInterval(int begin, int end, double step, FindMinI func)
    {
        double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        for (int i = begin; i <= end ; i += step) {

            if(func.function(i) <= min)
                min = func.function(i);

        }
        return min;
    }
 }
```

Comment: if step is `0` how will it ever end?

Comment: How can you have an *integer* value between `0` and `1`?

Comment: What do you mean step is `[0;1)` do this mean that you try with step not an integer??

Comment: Why do you use an `int` for begin and end, but a `double` for step?

Comment: Aww, sorry, I meant (0:1). Fixed

Comment: If you want to delete use delete option .Don't vandalize your post.

Comment: @Shree The delete option is unavailable due to the highly upvoted answer below.

Comment: what is the purpose of function(double x)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you try with step between `(0,1)` this will be casted to int when adding to `i`, as a result you will add `0` to `i` in every iteration which will lead to infinite loop!

Answer (score 2):

It will be infinite, because if `step` is **0** then adding zero to **i** would do nothing. No incrementation means infinite loop.

Comment: Either step is 0 or 0.001 or 0.5, loop becomes infinite

Comment: @RaiseLtwiCe Again, how can you have that *as an integer?* What happens when you convert `0.5` into an `int` value?

Answer (score 2):

If step is 0 you're adding 0 to `i` meaning there's nothing being added to the value, and it gets stuck as infinite.

Since you supply step as a double, having values like 0.0001 is possible. However, since `i` is an integer the conversion is made from double to int, and 0.0001 -> 0. When you cast a value that's less than 1 and more than 0 as an integer, it becomes 0.

Change `i` to `double` and you can use decimal values to increment.

Alternatively, you could change `step` to `int`, but you wouldn't be able to use decimal steps in that case

A similar situation can be found with division or multiplication to demonstrate the double example:

```
(int) (500 * 0.0001) -> 0.05 as an integer = 0
```

So when you add a double step with a decimal value (exclusively a decimal value) to an integer, step becomes `0`, `0` is added to `i` and it becomes infinite.

Comment: @Aominè Maybe, but if OP wants to increment a decimal, changing it to double (or float) is the only way to go

Answer (score 0):

When it is (0,1) always its a satisfying condition, the loop never ends.

Answer (score 0):

When it is (0,1), inside for loop you are verifying i <= end, this is all time passing condition. So, your loop won't break.